# How would I add some small text on a category line?

Tags: xetex, pdftex, moderncv

How would I add some small gray text on the right side of the selected projects line? 
[image]

I would want the text to be on the line, smaller font, and gray. I tried using /tiny but couldn't find a way to change the individual element color and reposition it to the right.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,sans]{moderncv}      
% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{banking}                             % style options are 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{red}                               % color options 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'

\usepackage[scale=0.85]{geometry}
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}                % if you want to change the width of the column with the dates
%\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm}           % for the 'classic' style, if you want to force the width allocated to your name and avoid line breaks. be careful though, the length is normally calculated to avoid any overlap with your personal info; use this at your own typographical risks...
\usepackage{multicol}

% personal data
\name{My}{Name}
\title{Designer/Developer}
\address{123 Main Street}{Anytown, USA 20192}
\phone[mobile]{(555) 555-5555}                
\email{dasasd@gmail.com}                            
\homepage{www.asdasd.com}                        
\social[linkedin]{asdasdasd}                                    
\social[github]{asdasdasd}                                                                        

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\vspace*{-13mm}
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{0.15\textwidth}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Selected Projects}

\hspace*{\fill}
\begin{minipage}{\maincolumnwidth}
 \begin{multicols}{2}
   \textbf{\href{http://google.com/}{Google}}
   \begin{itemize}
     \item Googley Google
   \end{itemize}
   \columnbreak
   \textbf{\href{https://asdasdds.com}{asdasdasdasdasd}}
   \begin{itemize}
        \item asdasdads
   \end{itemize}
 \end{multicols}
\end{minipage}

\hspace*{\fill}
\begin{minipage}{\maincolumnwidth}
 \begin{multicols}{2}
   \textbf{\href{http://adsasd.com}{asdasdasd}}
   \begin{itemize}
     \item asdasdasd
   \end{itemize}
   \columnbreak
   \textbf{\href{https://asdasdd.com}{asdasdasdasd}}
   \begin{itemize}
     \item adsasdasdasd
   \end{itemize}
 \end{multicols}
\end{minipage}     
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here, I put it all the way to the right.  Is that desired?  This was the key line:

```
\section{Selected Projects\hfill\scriptsize\textcolor{gray}{small text goes here}}
```

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,sans]{moderncv}      
% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{banking}                             % style options are 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{red}                               % color options 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'

\usepackage[scale=0.85]{geometry}
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}                % if you want to change the width of the column with the dates
%\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm}           % for the 'classic' style, if you want to force the width allocated to your name and avoid line breaks. be careful though, the length is normally calculated to avoid any overlap with your personal info; use this at your own typographical risks...
\usepackage{multicol}

% personal data
\name{My}{Name}
\title{Designer/Developer}
\address{123 Main Street}{Anytown, USA 20192}
\phone[mobile]{(555) 555-5555}                
\email{dasasd@gmail.com}                            
\homepage{www.asdasd.com}                        
\social[linkedin]{asdasdasd}                                    
\social[github]{asdasdasd}                                                                        

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\vspace*{-13mm}
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{0.15\textwidth}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Selected Projects\hfill\scriptsize\textcolor{gray}{small text goes here}}

\hspace*{\fill}
\begin{minipage}{\maincolumnwidth}
 \begin{multicols}{2}
   \textbf{\href{http://google.com/}{Google}}
   \begin{itemize}
     \item Googley Google
   \end{itemize}
   \columnbreak
   \textbf{\href{https://asdasdds.com}{asdasdasdasdasd}}
   \begin{itemize}
        \item asdasdads
   \end{itemize}
 \end{multicols}
\end{minipage}

\hspace*{\fill}
\begin{minipage}{\maincolumnwidth}
 \begin{multicols}{2}
   \textbf{\href{http://adsasd.com}{asdasdasd}}
   \begin{itemize}
     \item asdasdasd
   \end{itemize}
   \columnbreak
   \textbf{\href{https://asdasdd.com}{asdasdasdasd}}
   \begin{itemize}
     \item adsasdasdasd
   \end{itemize}
 \end{multicols}
\end{minipage}     
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Woah this is perfect! Didn't know of the \scriptsize command. Thanks!

Comment: I'd propose `\newcommand{\note}[1]{\hfill{\scriptsize\color{gray}#1}}`

Comment: @niraj P.115 of the LaTeX user guide shows the available reduced text sizes include `\small`, `\footnotesize`, `\scriptsize`, and `\tiny`.  Also note egreg's suggestion to create a macro named `\note`.  In this way, one would use the syntax `\section{Selected Projects\note{small text goes here}}`.